# DirectX 10 swap chain scaling

Tags: c++, directx

I want to disable swap chain scaling on windows.
I'm rendering 1600x900 quad on the top of window (1366x768) but it's streched.

```
Desc_.BufferCount        = 1;
Desc_.OutputWindow       = windowWnd;
Desc_.Windowed           = true;
Desc_.BufferDesc.Format  = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
Desc_.BufferDesc.Height  = height;
Desc_.BufferDesc.Width   = width;
Desc_.BufferUsage        = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
Desc_.SampleDesc.Count   = 1;
Desc_.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
Desc_.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
Desc_.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
swapChainDesc_.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering =  DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_PROGRESSIVE;
Desc_.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
Desc_.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
Desc_.Flags = 0;
```

this is initialization of DXGI swap chain

Comment: So you want to cut it off instead of scaling? Why do you render 1600x900 in the first place?

Comment: no I don't want to cut it. I want to scroll window client side and see what is in client area.

Comment: Then just render the appropriate part in the correct resolution.

Comment: what about DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS ?
It contains functionality supporting scrolling window contents.